# How to append custom components as string React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

This is my second day first day learning react and I came across problem that I could solve in a better way but I don't know how it is done in React.

```
import ExpenseItem from './ExpenseItem';
import './Expenses.css';

function Expenses(props) {
  const { items } = props;
  // const html = items
  //   .map(el => {
  //     return `
  //     <ExpenseItem
  //       title={${el.title}}
  //       amount={${el.amount}}
  //       date={${el.date}}
  //     ></ExpenseItem>`;
  //   })
  //   .join('');
  // console.log(html);

  return (
    <div className="expenses">
      <ExpenseItem
        title={items[0].title}
        amount={items[0].amount}
        date={items[0].date}
      />
      <ExpenseItem
        title={items[1].title}
        amount={items[1].amount}
        date={items[1].date}
      />
      <ExpenseItem
        title={items[2].title}
        amount={items[2].amount}
        date={items[2].date}
      />
      <ExpenseItem
        title={items[3].title}
        amount={items[3].amount}
        date={items[3].date}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Expenses;
```

So this is the thing. I am hardcoding 4  custom components because that is the length of props.items array.

Code that I commented out will create template literal based on length of items array, so for each item I will have created component. That is all fine but here comes the problem.

I don't know how to append that to the div with class name of "expenses".

That is problem I have.

Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: You can directly map the components inside the parent div. No need to convert to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map `items` array in return and it will render `ExpenseItem` for all items in array.

Try something like this:-

```
import ExpenseItem from './ExpenseItem';
import './Expenses.css';

function Expenses(props) {
  const { items } = props;

  return (
    <div className="expenses">
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <ExpenseItem
          key={item.id || index}
          title={item.title}
          amount={item.amount}
          date={item.date}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Expenses;
```

Comment: This solution works you just need one closing bracket before closing curly bracket. It renders is but also it throws me this error "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: My bad! forgot to add closing bracket. I have updated answer and also added key prop so it will remove unique key warning. If your item does not contain id and contains any other unique value then you can replace key with that unique value.